# Can Gerrit trigger be configured for maven project

Tags: jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have set up Gerrit server on SERVER_GERRIT. I have jenkins running on SERVER_JENKINS. I have installed Gerrit trigger on SERVER_JENKINS and done required settings on SERVER_GERRIT for jenkins user. I have configured a MAVEN job to build git repo present on SERVER_GERRIT whenever a patch set is created. The job is getting triggered as expected but it always fails because it tries to find pom.xml on SERVER_JENKINS rather than building the patchset on SERVER_GERRIT.
Any idea what am I missing? Is their a different plugin for maven projects?

Comment: Are you using Git plugin on Jenkins to clone the repository (where pom.xml is) on SERVER_GERRIT?

Comment: No. I have cloned repository on SERVER_GERRIT separately. I am able to invoke jenkins jobwhenever any patchset is created. But that build job looks for pom.xml in SERVER_JENKINS which it doesn't find. So build fails and scores my patchset as - Verified = -1.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Git Plugin on Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) so your Gerrit repository will be cloned/fetched at the SERVER_JENKINS by the Jenkins job and the pom.xml will be find correctly.